# How do I get a dataframe row to a list the index number?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a problem here let's say that I have this dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 1], [1, 3, 2], [4, 6, 3], [4, 3, 4], [5, 4, 5]], columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])

>> df
   A  B  C
0  1  2  1
1  1  3  2
2  4  6  3
3  4  3  4
4  5  4  5
```

Let's say that I have to get the row where A = 4:

2  4  6  3 and  3  4  3  4

How can I convert these data to a list WITH THE INDEX number?

Paulo

Comment: `df[df['A']==4].index`.

Comment: `df[df['A']==4]` to filter only

Comment: What do you mean by "with the index"?
Can you provide some sample of the expected output?

Answer (score 1):

You only want all that data to be in a list? How about something like this:

```py
>>> df.reset_index(drop=False).query('A == 4').values.tolist()
[[2, 4, 6, 3], [3, 4, 3, 4]]
```

Where the index is the 0th item in each sublist, and the values for each column are the remaining items in each sublist (i.e. from indexes 1 to 3)

Resetting the index using `reset_index(drop=False)` simply adds an `index` column to the DataFrame, consisting of whatever you index was previously, and makes it easy to get all these data into your list-sublist format.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer! The thing is: that I don't want to reset the dataframe index. I just want to extract the rows with the existing indexes. So the remaining dataframe will contain the rows with the indexes: 0, 1 and 4

Comment: Seeing as your current index is identical to what would be produced by `df.reset_index`, it doesn't really matter. This is what you need, it seems: `df[df['A'] == 4]`, as others have mentioned. The only two rows where that condition is true is at the 2nd and 3rd indices – not sure why you're asking for the 0th, 1st, and 4th indices instead (which don't match the `A == 4` condition).

Answer (score 0):

Use filtering

This should work

```
df[df.A == 4]
```